# regex to filter version from string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following strings:

String 1-

```
Cisco IOS Software, C3900 Software (C3900-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.4(3)M3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2) ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 15.0(1r)M16, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
```

String2-

```
Cisco IOS XE Software, Version 16.05.01b
Cisco IOS Software [Everest], ISR Software (X86_64_LINUX_IOSD-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 16.5.1b, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
licensed under the GNU General Public License ("GPL") Version 2.0.  The
software code licensed under GPL Version 2.0 is free software that comes
GPL code under the terms of GPL Version 2.0.  For more details, see the
```

from both the strings I need to get only `16.05.01b` and `15.4(3)M3` when I run Regex.

I have tried this `r'((?<=Version\s)\d+\.\d+\(\d+...)'`
I am able to fetch `15.4(3)M3` not `16.05.01b`.

and `r'((?<=Version\s)\d+\.\d+\(\d+...)'`

one regular expression should be able to fetch the version from both the strings, but both do not give me the result.

Comment: `re.match(r'^Cisco IOS .* Version ([^,\n]+),?', text).group(1)`

Answer (score 3):

In your examples a version is prefixed with `Version` and includes:

- numbers
- dots
- parentheses
- characters

Here, I model version as something that starts with a number and continues with a combination of the items above.

This should work:

```py
import re
strings = [
    '-M), Version 15.4(3)M3, RELEA',
    'rap, Version 15.0(1r)M16, RELEA',
    ', Version 16.5.1b, RELEASE',
    're, Version 16.05.01b'
]
version_re = re.compile(r'version (\d[\w.()]+)', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
for s in strings:
    v = version_re.search(s).group(1)
    print(v)
```

output:

```
15.4(3)M3
15.0(1r)M16
16.5.1b
16.05.01b
```

Comment: This will match more than the versions listed in the question `i need to get only 16.05.01b and 15.4(3)M3` Note that `\w` also matches `\d` and that you don't have to escape the dot and the parenthesis. It might be written as `\d[.()\w]+` and does not take and opening and a matching closing parenthesis into account.

Comment: The strings he gave look like `--version` outputs, which tend to stay consistent across versions. So, he could just take the first matches in both strings. 

_Note that \w also matches \d and that you don't have to escape the dot and the parenthesis._ Cool, TIL.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's because your regex expects to find a parenthesis when searching for the version, which is not present in the second string.

This is an easy way to solve it (borrowed the strings from abdusco):

```
strings = [
    '-M), Version 15.4(3)M3, RELEA',
    'rap, Version 15.0(1r)M16, RELEA',
    ', Version 16.5.1b, RELEASE']

    versions = []
    version = re.compile(r'(?<=Version\s)\d+\.\d........')
        for s in strings:
            v = version.search(s).group(0).split(',')[0]
            version.append(v)
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was enough to point out the offending part such that the poster could try to correct the solution on its own. 
I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an alternation to  get both the values.

You might also omit the capturing group as it is the only match to match either an opening till closing parenthesis followed by A-Z and a digit or match a dot, 2 digits and a character a-z

```
(?<=Version\s)\d+\.\d+(?:\([^()+]\)[A-Z]\d|\.\d{2}[a-z])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qbT0jW/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/le45zP)

A more efficient version could be using a capturing group instead of the lookbehind:

```
Version\s(\d+\.\d+(?:\([^()+]\)[A-Z]\d|\.\d{2}[a-z]))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qbT0jW/2)

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=Version\s)\d+\.\d+(?:\([^()+]\)[A-Z]\d|\.\d{2}[a-z])"

test_str = ("String 1-Cisco IOS Software, C3900 Software (C3900-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.4(3)M3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)\n"
    "ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 15.0(1r)M16, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)\n\n"
    "String2-Cisco IOS XE Software, Version 16.05.01b\n"
    "Cisco IOS Software [Everest], ISR Software (X86_64_LINUX_IOSD-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 16.5.1b, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)\n"
    "licensed under the GNU General Public License (\"GPL\") Version 2.0.  The\n"
    "software code licensed under GPL Version 2.0 is free software that comes\n"
    "GPL code under the terms of GPL Version 2.0.  For more details, see the")

print (re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

Result

```
['15.4(3)M3', '16.05.01b']
```